# How can I tell mypy that a condition is guaranteed?

Tags: python-3.6, mypy

My actual case is more complicated, but the MVCE is

```
from typing import List


def find_largest(numbers: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """
    >>> find_largest([3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 1, -2, 4, 3, 3])
    [5, 5]
    """
    assert len(numbers) > 0  # guaranteed by caller
    largest_numbers = None
    value = None
    for number in numbers:
        if value is None or number > value:
            largest_numbers = [number]
            value = number
        elif number == value:
            largest_numbers.append(number)
    return largest_numbers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

When I run mypy on this, I get:

```
mytest.py:18: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[List[int]]", expected "List[int]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

But restrictions which are not captured by mypy guarantee that None is not returned. How can I hint that to mypy? (Initializing with something else is NOT possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can still return None according to Mypy and the it thinks the typing is correct.

Assuming you can't fix this you could also force the return to always have a value with:

```
assert largest_numbers
return largest_numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

> To the type checker this signals that the return value has the designated type, but at runtime we intentionally don’t check anything (we want this to be as fast as possible).

```py
from typing import List, cast
...

def find_largest(numbers: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """
    >>> find_largest([3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 1, -2, 4, 3, 3])
    [5, 5]
    """
    assert len(numbers) > 0  # guaranteed by caller
    largest_numbers = None
    value = None
    for number in numbers:
        if value is None or number > value:
            largest_numbers = [number]
            value = number
        elif number == value:
            largest_numbers.append(number)
    return cast(List[int], largest_numbers)
...
```